# In Javascript, why are \b characters dropped in a .join()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript, why does this statement not equal `'\b,\b'`?

```
['\b', '\b'].join()
//=> ","
```

According to MDN docs on `join`:

> If an element is undefined or null, it is converted to the empty string.

So why is `\b` being evaluated as undefined/null?

Additionally, the`\b` is dropped from any string prepended with it, e.g:

```
['\btest', '\btest2'].join()
//=> "test,test2"
```

Something crazy is going on.

Comment: type `"\b"` in your console, it will return an empty string

Comment: @gurvinder372 yeah it does, but why? `\a` returns 'a', which is strange too. What's this back slash character doing?

Comment: Its a special character. Try to use double backslash b - `\\b`

Comment: `\b` is defined right at the top of the [MDN page on strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notatio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why is \b being evaluated as undefined/null?

As per the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-identifier-names-static-semantics-stringvalue)

> In determining the sequence any occurrences of \
>   UnicodeEscapeSequence are first replaced with the code point
>   represented by the UnicodeEscapeSequence and then the code points of
>   the entire IdentifierName are converted to code units by UTF16Encoding
>   (10.1.1) each code point.

Also read [this part](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-string-literals) to understand which are escape character and which are not

> **CharacterEscapeSequence** ::
>
> SingleEscapeCharacter NonEscapeCharacter
>
> **SingleEscapeCharacter** ::
>
> one of ' " \ b f n r t v
>
> **NonEscapeCharacter**
>
> :: SourceCharacter but not one of EscapeCharacter or LineTerminator
>
> **EscapeCharacter** ::
>
> SingleEscapeCharacter
>
> DecimalDigit x u
>
> **HexEscapeSequence** ::
>
> x HexDigit HexDigit UnicodeEscapeSequence :: u
>   Hex4Digits u{ HexDigits }

Which is why `\b` being a special character is removed while `\a` is still "a".

Comment: @ccnokes, check this answer for **why** this is happening.

Comment: You're quoting the wrong part of the spec. `b` is not a "UnicodeEscapeSequence", which is a hex number prefixed by `u`. You are looking for the production called "SingleEscapeCharacter".

Comment: @torazaburo updated the answer to include what is an escape character and what is not.

Answer (score 1):

> `\b` is a special character, which means backspace.

That is why it is being converted to the 'empty' string.

[Reference:](http://javascript.info/tutorial/string)